# Handling action parameter within a component in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Why does my `<button>` work but the `{{delete-toggle}}` component gives me an undefined for the message variable?

```html
{{delete-toggle action='deleteMessage' message=message}}

<button {{action 'deleteMessage' message}}>Some Action (param: {{message}}</button>
```

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: '',
    actions: {
        deleteMessage(message){ 
            console.log(message); 
            return this.sendAction('deleteMessage', message);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your action on the inside supposed to be `deleteMessage`?  And you're missing a mustache on `message`, but I'm going to guess this was just a typo in the question.  And is your sendAction supposed to be `deleteMessage`?

Comment: Ups those were just errors in the question. I fixed it. It was already late... `{{delete-toggle}}` is a predefined button component that I'm using in different parts of the app. The action itself is firing. The `<button>` element that I put for test purposes is doing what it is supposed to do. Just the `{{delete-toggle}}` is logging undefined.

Comment: And message shows up in the UI, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{delete-toggle}}` component is triggering the default action with no parameter, but your `deleteMessage` action handler requires one. The button, on the other hand, is explicitly passing along the parameter in its `{{action 'deleteMessage' message}}` specifier.

Why pass the parameters around anyway, since the component already knows the message involved?

```
{{delete-toggle action='deleteMessage' message=message}}

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    // ATTRIBUTES
    message: null,

    // ACTIONS
    actions: {
        deleteMessage(){ 
            var message = this.get('message');
            console.log(message); 
            this.sendAction('deleteMessage', message);
        }
    }

});
```

You can then write the button a bit more simply as

```
<button {{action 'deleteMessage'}}>Some Action (param: {{message}}</button>
```

BTW, I would not recommend empty tags. Is there some reason you are doing that? Also, I don't think returning a value from an action handler does anything useful.

Comment: This way it is just giving me 'null' for both. The empty tag was to remove an unnecessary `<div>` I'm returning the value from the action handler to send it from the component to the route. The `<button>`element is just for test purposes to see if it would work if it had a value for `message`. The `<button>` element was working with my previous setup.